# Change text at every time interval - React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to change a text (it begins automatically when the screen appears) at every time interval in react, but the problem is that, the time given isn't respected, and the text is changing at a random time interval.
This is a part of my code:

```
const names = [
    'tony', 'elias', 'fadi'
]

const [newName, setnewName] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
    for (const [index, value] of names.entries()) {
        setTimeout(() => { shuffle(value) }, 5000);
    }
})

const shuffle = (value) => {
    setnewName(value);
}
```

And thank you!

Comment: Does this help. Instead of time call shuffle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63604185/setinterval-updating-state-in-react-but-not-recognizing-when-time-is-0/63604505#63604505

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Couple things here, but the main issue is the use of `setTimeout` in a `useEffect` call with no dependency array. So you're calling `shuffle` 5000ms after each render, which is why the updates seem to occur at random times. Additionally, the way `shuffle` is called looks like it will pose some issues.

You should modify your code so that the `shuffle` function selects a random element from the `names` array on its own and only call `shuffle` one time (you might also consider renaming `shuffle` to something like `selectRandomName`). Then change `setTimeout` to `setInterval` and only call that on mount (instead of on each render).

Here's a full example:

```js
const names = [
    'tony', 'elias', 'fadi'
]

function MyComponent() {
    const [newName, setnewName] = useState("");

    const shuffle = useCallback(() => {
        const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length);
        setnewName(names[index]);
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        const intervalID = setInterval(shuffle, 5000);
        return () => clearInterval(intervalID);
    }, [shuffle])

    return(
        <Text>name:{newName}</Text>
    )
}
```

Note the use of `useCallback` here is to prevent `useEffect` from running on each render while also preventing linter warnings from showing up.

Answer (score 1):

There is also another way of doing it using `setTimeout` like so:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"

const names = [
  'tony', 'elias', 'fadi'
]

export default function MyComponent() {
  const [currentName, setCurrentName] = useState(names[0]);

  function setRandomName() {
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length);
    let newName = names[index]
    if (newName == currentName) { setRandomName() }
    else { setCurrentName(newName) }
    return
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setRandomName()
    }, 1000);
  }, [currentName])

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>name:{currentName}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here I'm using a recursive function for setting the random name because by doing it this way if the name name is repeated on an interval then the function runs again until a new different name is set.

The actual time interval is happening within `useEffect`, what I'm doing here is simply setting a timeout. This works because I'm passing `currentName` as a dependency to `useEffect` so the code within `useEffect` will run every time `currentName` changes, which will continue happening becaue every time `useEffect` runs it changes the value of `currentName`.

To show the simplicity of the actual time interval here's an example where we simply go through the list in order instead of randomly every second until we reach the end of the array.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"

const names = [
  'tony', 'elias', 'fadi'
]

export default function MyComponent() {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0)
  useEffect(() => {
    if (index == names.length - 1) return
    setTimeout(() => {
      setIndex(index + 1)
    }, 1000);
  }, [index])

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>name:{names[index]}</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here we use the index starting in 0 as a dependency instead and we increment it by one every time the interval runs as long as it's less than the lenght of `names`.